# CAML query to enable/disable custom ribbon button

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, caml-query

I have a custom list and when the user open the list item Display form there is a custom ribbon. This ribbon should be enabled if the current user is a member of a particular Group. Here is the caml query i used

```
var id = JSRequest.QueryString["ID"];
if (contextKey == "ApproveRequest") {
    var condition = '<View>' + 
                        '<Query>' + 
                            '<Where>' + 
                                '<And>' + 
                                    '<Eq>' + 
                                        '<FieldRef Name=\"ID\"></FieldRef>' + 
                                        '<Value Type=\"Integer\">' + id + '</Value>' + 
                                    '</Eq>' + 
                                    '<Or>' + 
                                        '<Membership Type="SPGroup" ID="447">' + 
                                            '<FieldRef Name=\"Author\"/>' + 
                                        '</Membership>' + 
                                        '<Eq>' + 
                                            '<FieldRef Name= \"Author\"/>' + 
                                            '<Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer"/></Value>' + 
                                        '</Eq>' + 
                                    '</Or>' + 
                                '</And>' + 
                            '</Where>' + 
                        '</Query>' + 
                    '</View>';
}
```

but the above Code is  not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to check if the current user is a member of a particular group, then show or hide the custom ribbon button.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
    isMember("Some Group Name").done(function(){
        if(data.d.results[0] != undefined){
            //show the custom ribbon 
        }else{
            //hide the custom ribbon
        }
    });
});
function isMember(groupName){
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+ groupName +"')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
    });
}
</script>
```

Or use the JSOM code to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Usage
function IsCurrentUserWithContributePerms() 
{
  IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        // The current user is in the [Members] group
    }
  });

}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserWithContributePerms, 'SP.js');
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {

        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = context.get_web();

        var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
        context.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        context.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        context.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        context.load(groupUsers);

        context.executeQueryAsync(
                function(sender, args) {
                   var userInGroup = IsUserInGroup(currentUser,group);         
                   OnComplete(userInGroup);
                },
                function OnFailure(sender, args) {
                   OnComplete(false);
                }
        );

        function IsUserInGroup(user,group)
        {
            var groupUsers = group.get_users();
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == user.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return userInGroup;
        }
}
</script>
```

Or the article below for your reference.

[Enable\Disable Ribbon button by Users Group SharePoint](http://sampathnarsingam.blogspot.com/2012/07/enabledisable-ribbon-button-by-users.html)